# NullReferenceException in MySqlClient.NativeDriver

Tags: c#, sql, mysql, nullreferenceexception

I have a long running program that exectues some mySQL-Queries every 5 minutes (timed thread). After it has run for approximately 10 hours a NullReferenceException is thrown with the following stacktrace:

```
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int32& insertedId)
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int32& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Close()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ResetReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at MyOwnProgram.Mysql.sendData(String sqlCommmand)
```

The sendData method is the following (lockDB is of type Object)

```
public void sendData(string sqlCommmand) {
            try {
                using(MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
                    command.CommandTimeout = 5;
                    command.CommandText = sqlCommmand;
                    lock(lockDB) {
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            } catch(MySqlException e) {
                throw e;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                // do some logging
            }
        }
```

The connection is opened when calling the constructor of the mySQL-Class and disposed when calling the destructor or calling dispose(). Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you leaving the connection handling to ADO.NET:

```
public void sendData(string sqlCommmand) 
{
    using (var con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand()) 
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 5;
        cmd.CommandText = sqlCommmand;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

You no longer need the `finally` statement. You could add `try/catch` if you need to log something but make sure to propagate the exception and not consume it.

Comment: what stands against creating the connection when calling the constructor of the MySQL-Class?

Comment: The connection string to the database.

Comment: can you explain it in more detail? My connection string is stored in a settings file. The connection is stored in a class variable and created by connection = new MySqlConnection(Settings.Default.ConnectionString);

Comment: I mean why can't I create the connection in the construtor of the mysql class and leave it alive for the runtime of the program?

Comment: ADO.NET uses a connection pool. Connections are not created everytime you sent a SQL query. They are drawn from the pool and it is better to leave this handling to the framework.

Comment: @Xelluloid Did this solution (provided by @DarinDimitrov) worked? I am facing such issue as well.

Comment: Worked for me on a response that takes 5 minutes and returns 1M records